# Forcing users to pick a name

Tags: discussion, new-users, display-names, question-quality

**EDIT: I am convinced that this is not a very helpfull idea.**

When I first found Stack Overflow I was amazed at the speed at which people answered my questions. The quality was amazing as well and I solved a lot of issues with the help of this community.

Over time I started to feel the urge to give back. Nowadays I spend most of my idle time at work helping to answer PHP questions on SO.

What I keep running into is ungrateful people who do not bother reading answers, clicking links or even putting the tiniest bit of effort into providing the information needed to solve their issues.

Those users mostly have a name that starts with "user" and is followed by a long random number. Because they care so little, they didn't even bother to pick a nickname.

I co-run a free DIY Self-help Bike Workshop. Basically people come in, they can use the tools for free, we provide recycled parts that we get from donated old bikes and we help people to fix their bikes.

Sometimes, people come in and just demand that we fix their bike for free and they demand modern, quality parts and someone even suggest we just bring him the bike to his house once we finished fixing it.

My Point is: Maybe the registration process does not have to be **that** easy.

It might end up destroying a community that is already flooded with very low quality questions.

Comment: And by forcing people to input a name everything gets better. Come on :)

Comment: So what do you do when someone like that comes into the shop? Ask their name?

Comment: I don't want to change my name.

Comment: @Geobits No. We changed from explaining to them how the shop works to simply pointing to a sign that explains it and they only get service when they have read it. Before we all spend hours explaining over and over and ending up in discussions

Comment: If I did not want to have a customized name but were *forced* to, I'd enter something like "asdfasdf", append a number to it if needed, and call it a day.

Comment: Strongly related to: [Don't allow questions from a user unless they have proven their worth/interest somehow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95080)

Comment: @juergend Surely not. But i have the feeling that it sends the wrong message if you are allowed to not even take the time to pick a username.

Comment: Exactly, and that's basically what you should do here. Either explain how the site works(politely), or point them to the FAQs and help pages. Or, if you're tired of doing those, *just ignore it*, which is an option you don't always have face-to-face. None of those things require anything added to the registration process.

Comment: Well i asked for Discussion, i got feedback. That's all i wanted. Maybe i just grew tired of people who took ages to understand that if everybody tells them they need more detail to answer, it is a good idea to provide more detail. 
Hopefully the ongoing downvoting by people who disagre will not completely destroy my reputation :)

Comment: I fail to see how having usernames like `asdfghjklwiebd` will be any better. I also have no idea how a name contributes to quality at all.

Answer (score 3):

As I see there are many users who have more than 10k+ reputation with default username and doing everything perfectly.

Stackoverflow assign a default name like `userrandom` when someone create a account. It does not make strong if anyone pick a name that would do perfecly sure.

> It might end up destroying a community that is already flooded with very low quality questions.

If someone ask low quality questions or off-topic then here you should either downvote it and you can vote to close it also or even you can flag if you can not vote for close if you see here any spam or off-topic or low quality questions.

Answer (score 3):

Why just picking a name? Let's see how we can make new users life difficult, hoping they will get the point and become excellent users.

- Quiz: take 10 random interview questions and force them to answer. Less than 7 correct answers? The user can't have an account.
- Must answer at least 10 questions first and have at least one upvote on each answer before he can ask his own questions.

You see my point?

Comment: I do see your point and it did make me smile :D